# Help getting names in view for attachments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to display attachments in my asset view and I have this in my view:

```
<% if @asset.attachments.size > 0 %>
    <% @asset.attachments.each_with_index do |attachment| %>
    <%= image_tag attachment.to_s %>  
    <%end%>
    <%end%>
```

and I have this in my controller (just the basic):

```
 def show
@asset = Asset.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @asset }
end
```

end

When I want it to show the name (which is in the attachment field of the attachments table).  But the code only gives me

```
 #<attachment #<attachment
```

as output in the view.  What am I missing?

Comment: I found the solution. I needed `<% attachment.attachment.to_s %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `attachment` here is just referencing the class it looks like. Is there a name field for attachment so you could call something like `<%= image_tag attachment.name %>`?

Comment: The name field is attachment.  I realized I was calling the entire object just a bit ago, so yes, your answer is correct as `<%= image_stag attachment.attachment.to_s %>`